# Depth First Reading of large XML Files

Tags: xml, xslt, sax, depth-first-search

I need to process a bunch of very large XML files and read each element depth-first. Due to size, any `DOM` solution is out of question and things are further complicated by the fact that the actual element needed is not the "leaf" but its parent.

More specifically, the files have a structure like

```
    <Level 1>
        ...
        <Level 2>
            ...
            <Level N-1>
                <value>...</value>
                <value>...</value>
                ...
                <value>...</value>
            </Level N-1>
            <Level N-1>
                <value>...</value>
                <value>...</value>
                ...
                <value>...</value>
            </Level N-1>
            ...
            <Level N-1>
                <value>...</value>
                <value>...</value>
                ...
                <value>...</value>
            </Level N-1>
            ...
        </Level 2>
    </Level 1>
```

Out of each file like the above, the `<Level N-1>` elements need to be read individually (each including all the corresponding `<value>` elements). The depth, `N`, varies within each file and across files, so it is essentially unknown, as are `XML` tag names. Things are further complicated by the fact that `<value>` elements also exist in higher levels (i.e., they constitute no guarantee that `Level N` has been reached).

A quick solution for reading an entire XML element at a specific depth as a string is something like

```
int level = 0;  // The base level of the element, could be at any depth
Reader in = ... // The reader to the input
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(outStream);
XMLEventReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(in);
XMLEventWriter writer = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventWriter(out);
XMLEvent event;

while ((level > 0) && reader.hasNext());
{
    event = reader.nextEvent();

    if (event.isStartElement())
    {
        level++;
    }
    else if (event.isEndElement())
    {
        level--;
    }

    writer.add(event);
}

writer.flush();

String element = new String(outStream.toByteArray());
```

The above, however, is not helpful if the calling code does not know that a `Level N-1` element has been reached and it advances to `Level N` (i.e., to `<value>` elements).

A `SAX` solution would be ideal, but even preprocessing the file via an `XSLT` template is acceptable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify requirements a bit, perhaps with a sample input and desired output?

Comment: There is not much to be added to the data description above, only the tag names would change. Essentially, the idea is to group together all <value> elements at each Level-1 tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wanted XSLT pre-processing isn't possible in pure XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 because an XSLT processor (1.0 or 2.0) typically produces a representation (not necessarily DOM) of the whole XML document in memory.

In **[XSLT 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#streaming)** (still a WD) there will be streaming as part of the language, but this is still under active development by the W3C XSLT WG and the specification isn't yet stable.

Saxon has **[streaming extensions](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/sourcedocs/streaming/streaming-templates.xml)** in the form of streaming templates that are in a "streamable mode":

```
<xsl:mode name="s" streamable="yes"/>
```

using which it could be possible to produce XML documents each containing just the subtree rooted in an "Level N-1" element.

Comment: Well, XSLT means preprocessing so it is not the best option here. But even if it were, given your top XSLT skills, I assume from the description above that there is no way it can be done. Thanks for the answer, though! :-)

Comment: @PNS, It can be done today, if you use Saxon's streaming extensions. It will be possible to do in one year's time with any XSLT 3.0 streaming processor.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your issue correctly, you're having difficulty distinguishing when you get to a `<value>` tag and have finished going through the level tags

When you recognize an event, you can get further information like name out of it:

```
  if (event.isStartElement()) {
    StartElement element = (StartElement) event;
    System.out.println("Start Element: " + element.getName());
  }
```

If what you really want is the last level before this, of course you'll have to hold onto it.

Comment: Sure, but the problem is that I need to read the entire <Level N-1> tag and just reading a <value> element is not a guarantee that <Level N> has been reached.